# React import module working in development, but run build causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a script and exporting some functions from the script `createPalette.js` like this:

```
module.exports = { createPalette, generateFrameworkObject };
```

Then in React component `Main.jsx` I am importing the `createPalette` like this:

```
import { createPalette } from "../scripts/createPalette";
```

in development server it's working normally, but when trying to `npm run build` I get this error:

```
./src/components/Main.jsx
Attempted import error: 'createPalette' is not exported from '../scripts/createPalette'.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

How to fix this?

Comment: are you sure file name is createPalette.jsx not CreatePalette.jsx also check once in repository

Comment: @Nikhilbhatia the module file is createPalette.js, and the react component is Main.jsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you replace

```
module.exports = { createPalette, generateFrameworkObject };
```

by

```
export { createPalette, generateFrameworkObject }
```

?

You are mixing es6 export/import with the old one.

Comment: I guess I can do that, but how will I use it in Node command line to run tests and stuff. I thought Babel takes care of old to new import export thing